# problem with a code "initializer magnitude too large for specified size" on assembler

Tags: messagebox, invoke, assembler-warnings

code works in the following way:it solves the following problem "2d/a-21bd". then it should open a message box, where the result is shown. here is the code:

```
;include \masm64\include64\masm64rt.inc
.data         ;data for the code    
a dq  1       ;operand a  
b dq 0        ;operand b
c dq 21       ;number 21
d dq 5        ;operand d
q dq 2        ;number 2
res dq 0      ;result
title1 db "Решение уравнения. masm64",0                     ;title for the message box
txt1 db "Уравнение 2d/a-21bd",10,
"Результат: %d",10,"Адрес переменной в памяти: %ph",10,10,
"Автор:Тарадай Святослав",0                                 ;text for the message box
buf1 dq 3 dup(0),0                                          ;sorry, i don't know what does this code do. if you can say, i'll be happy
.code                       ;code area. solving a problem 2d/a-21bd         
entry_point proc
mov rax ,b          ;moving operand b to rax to make a second part of a problem
mul c               ;multiplying on 21
mul d               ;multiplying on d, or 5
mov rsi, rax        ;moving the result to rsi
mov rax,d           ;moving operand d, or 5 to rax, making a first part of the problem
mul q               ;multiplying on 2
xor rdx,rdx         ;preparing rdx to division
div a               ;division on a, or 1
sub rax,rsi         ;substraction of rsi(21bd) from rax(2d/a)
mov res,rax         ;moving result on res
invoke wsprintf,ADDR buf1,ADDR txt1,res, ADDR res1           ;transform function
invoke MessageBox,0,ADDR buf1,ADDR title1,MB_ICONINFORMATION ;output function
invoke ExitProcess,0
entry_point endp         
end
```

but i've got following errors with the invoke thing:

```
 Assembling: C:\masm64\bin64\a1.asm
C:\masm64\bin64\a1.asm(27) : error A2071:initializer magnitude too large for specified size
C:\masm64\bin64\a1.asm(27) : error A2008:syntax error : invokeC:\masm64\bin64\a1.asm(28) : error A2071:initializer magnitude too large for specified size
C:\masm64\bin64\a1.asm(28) : error A2008:syntax error : invokeC:\masm64\bin64\a1.asm(29) : error A2071:initializer magnitude too large for specified size
C:\masm64\bin64\a1.asm(29) : error A2008:syntax error : invokeLINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\masm64\bin64\a1.obj'
```

if you can help me with this one, because i'm a new one in assembler, i'll be very happy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the compilation.i used the makeit.bat wit RC. just changing it to simple makeit.bat solves the problem